# Replace first two zeros with a word

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

Is there anyway to replace first two zeros of a field with a 4 character word?

Example 1:

```
Input : 000183
Output: ABCD0183
```

Example 2:

```
Input : 006190
Output: ABCD6190
```

Comment: If the strings ALWAYS start with two zeros, you can just do `stuff([Input], 1, 2, 'ABCD')` That will replace the two characters following the first character with the string 'ABCD'.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `CHARINDEX` and limit to only instances where '00' appears at the start of the string.

Using Xedni's suggestion you could try:

```
SELECT STUFF([INPUT],1,2,'ABDC')
WHERE CHARINDEX('00',[INPUT]) = 1
```

The where clause will ensure that '00' are the first two characters of your input.